# Grabbing text from txt file into clipboard when ever the file is changed

Tags: powershell, clipboard

I have a server I connect to that does not allow copy paste. There is a shared drive i can access from both. I wrote a script on the local side to dump the clipboard into a text file any time i copy something. I'm having trouble reversing it on the remote side. I'm trying to monitor the file and if it sees the LastWriteTime change, grab the txt and dump it into the remote clip board. However, it seems that no matter what i try, it's WRITNG the LastWriteTime insteading of READING. Here's my code....

```
$copypath = "sharedrive\copy.txt"
$lastModifiedDate = Get-Item $copypath | select -Property LastWriteTime

for()
{
#$dateA = $lastModifiedDate 
$dateB = Get-ChildItem -Path $copypath $_.LastWriteTime

if ($dateA -ne $dateB) {
 get-content $copypath|set-clipboard
 $lastModifiedDate = (Get-Item $copypath).LastWriteTime
 }
}
```

tried Get-Item $copypath | select -Property LastWriteTime and Get-ChildItem -Path $copypath $_.LastWriteTime as well as LastAccessTime

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your are trying to access the `LastWriteTime` in three different ways, but only the third one is correct. Use that instead:

```
$copypath = "sharedrive\copy.txt"
$lastDate = (Get-Item $copypath).LastWriteTime

for() {
    $currentDate = (Get-Item $copypath).LastWriteTime

    if ($currentDate -ne $lastDate) {
        Get-Content $copypath | Set-Clipboard
        $lastDate = $currentDate
    }
}
```

An alternative with `Select-Object` would be:

```
Get-Item $copypath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime
```

---

Additional note: Your infinite loop is very expensive. Add a sleep time or use filesystem watchers instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.Refresh()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh?view=net-7.0#system-io-filesysteminfo-refresh) method from [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-7.0) if you keep the original instance instead of using `Select-Object`:

```bash
# store the FileInfo
$file = Get-Item $copypath
# store its LastWriteTime
$date = $file.LastWriteTime

# infinite loop
for() {
    # refresh the instance
    $file.Refresh()
    # if the dates are not equal
    if($date -ne $file.LastWriteTime) {
        # read the file and set clipboard
        $file | Get-Content -Raw | Set-Clipboard
        # update the new LastWriteTime
        $date = $file.LastWriteTime
    }
    # should use sleep here
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
}
```